# importxml to gather prices from undermine journal

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to automate the prices of items in a game to display on a spreadsheet (World of Warcraft). I am using TheUndermine journal to get prices.

link : https://theunderminejournal.com/#us/garona/item/23445

what I want to get is the Current Price to display in my spreadsheet. The site is updated hourly.

=importxml("https://theunderminejournal.com/#us/garona/item/23445","/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/table/tr[3]/td/span")

=importxml("https://theunderminejournal.com/#us/garona/item/23445","//*[@id="item-page"]/div[1]/table/tr[3]/td/span")

I have tried these but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. I have got this to work with other sites like retail sites and such, just not this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript generated sites can't be fetched by import functions of sheets.

Moreover, I tried fetching the current price using script via `UrlFetchApp` but it seems that I can't make it work.

I tried finding an alternative site but was not able to find one. If you can provide a similar/alternative site that can show a data similar to the one from TUJ, I might be able to give you a working script but import functions from sheet will definitely not work.

Comment: @AllanDuarte, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)